# Sh Script using ftp to put a list of files

Tags: shell, shell-script, ftp

So my Script looks something like this:

```
#...
files="$(find $line/processed/* 2>/dev/null)" #2>/dev/null used for error output suppression
if [[ ! -z "$files" ]]
then
                    #put_list="put"
                    #for word in $files; do
                    #       put_list="$put_list"$' '"$word"
                    #done

                    put_list="put $files" 
                    rm_list="rm $files"
yafc ftp://blabla@192.168.178.54  <<**
$put_list
close
quit
**
#...
```

So if I use it like that I get an error from yafc like this:

```
...
yafc 192.168.178.54:~/> No such command '/mnt/dir/processed/19,11,2014-14,17,25,,313', try 'help'
yafc 192.168.178.54:~/> No such command '/mnt/dir/processed/19,11,2014-14,17,41,,649"
...
```

Every file is listed here. Only the first file in `$files` was put right on the host.

But if I use this: (what is commented out in the code above)

```
put_list="put"
for word in $files; do
     put_list="$put_list"$' '"$word"
done
```

Everything works perfect!
So what is the difference? I tried to use `tr` to get rid of `'\n'`. If I `echo $put_list`, in both cases they (seem) to be identical. I don't want to iterate over $files because sometimes there are a lot of data in it, and it would take a lot of time.

So is it possible to do this job without this costly for-loop?

Comment: Does `yafc` work with `put file1 file2 file3` ? Or does it need `put file1`, `put file2` on separate lines? (Also, you don't need to start sentences with "So"...)

Comment: As it works with the for-loop, I guess it works with `put file1 file2 file3`

Comment: Who do you need to explicitly `close` and `quit`? Wouldn't `printf 'put %s\n' $(find ...) | yafc ftp://192.168.178.54/` do what you want?

Answer (score 1):

```
files=$(echo $line/processed/*)
yafc ftp://blabla@192.168.178.54  <<**
put $files
close
quit
**
```

The `find` command separates found files with newlines (one file per line). As you don't actually seem to need the find functionality you can use `files=$(echo $line/processed/*)`.

The here document expanded to

```
put file1
file2
file3
...
```

When you tried the loop, you didn't use quotes so the newlines were interpreted as field separators and so each file was separated by the space you added.

By using the simple `files=$(echo $line/processed/*)` `$files` now just has spaces between the files, so `put $files` should do what you want.